# Overlapping error in anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I've installed anaconda3 4.4.0 for Python 3.6.1. but its not working as at  the time of installation of further packages it shows data fetching errors and do not initiate spyder, jupyter notebook and any other packages.

While opening spyder, it says that spyder has been crashed. I've set its settings to default for several times but its still not opening. Moreover, I've tried to manually launch jupyter notebook and spyder by using ANACONDA NAVIGATOR but it also gives error. (the error is given below)

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\Shumail_Jaffar\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio__init__.py", line 16, in 
>   from . import _overlapped
>   ImportError: cannot import name '_overlapped'

Comment: anaconda 4.40 for python 3.5 would be more correct

Comment: Do you have any other versions of Python Installed?  The only time I have seen something like this happen is when multiple versions of Python were getting in the way.  Perhaps try removing anaconda and do a fresh install, making sure to check the box 'make anaconda default Python'

Comment: sorry, that was a mistake. I'm using anaconda3 4.4.0 for python 3.6

Comment: no I have no other versions, plus I've reinstalled it for several times its still not working. and at every time of installation I've marked "make anaconda default Python"

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.